# Рендеринг DOM-дерева

Tags: javascript, парсер, api, dom, crawling

**Внимание, перед тем как минусовать, приведите пример и прочитайте обсуждение в чате**

Почему все известные библиотеки (ровно как и неизвестные) для парсинга занимаются построением DOM-дерева? Это очень дорогая операция. Я не понимаю, зачем её делать, когда ровно также я могу выцепить в коде html-документа нужные мне теги и атрибуты и ориентироваться на них. Далее очень легко получить нужные данные.

Если же после загрузки html-сраницы, начинают работать js-скрипты, то максимум, что они могут сделать -- это запросить данные из API. Это очень легко отслеживается через консоль разработчика в любом браузере. И тогда эти же запросы можно делать скриптами и получать нужные данные.

Да, Вы можете сказать, что ответы от API могут приходить зашифрованными. Но это встречается в 1 случае из нескольких тысяч. Единственное место, где я видел такое -- это некоторые сервисы google. Даже Яндекс с такими вещами не запаривается. Ровно как и многие другие компании.

Я думаю, что такой подход идёт от selenium-подобных утилит, которые предназначаются для других задач. В частности, для тестирования. Там такие кейсы скорее всего актуальны. И то, вероятно, можно обходиться без них. Но, всё-таки, покуда там преследуются иные цели, понять это можно.

Если Вы знаете иные библиотеки, которые делают это напрямую, прошу рассказать о них.

**Примеры библиотек**: [ferret](https://github.com/MontFerret/ferret), [bs4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)

**Примеры**
Самый простой пример. HTML:

`<x>Hello world!<z>a</z></x>`

Нам нужно извлечь содержимое тега `<z>`:

- Найти позицию `</z>`
- Извлечь, начиная с `<z>` и до `</z>` нужные данные
- Success!

Пример сложнее, с контекстом. Извлечь данные из `<x>` (извлечь `a`):

`<x>Hello world!<z><x>a</x></z>`

- Найти позицию тега `<z>`
- Найти позицию тега `<x>`
- Извлечь данные от `<x>` до `</x>`
- Success!

**Пример из комментов**:

`<a href="#">>>><b>>текст><!-- комент --></div>`

- Найти позицию `>><b>>`
- Найти позицию `><!--`
- Извлечь данные от `>><b>>` до `><!--`
- Success!

## Пример реализации подхода

[CFE](https://github.com/Hedgehogues/cfe/releases). Я сделал простую библиотечку, как говорил в обсуждениях. Желающие могут ознакомиться. На текущий момент она сырая и вряд ли приспособлена для промышленного использования кем-то ещё, кроме меня. Это связано с тем, что есть ещё слишком много деталей, которые требуют шлифовки для того, чтобы с ней можно было удобно работать.

Кроме того, я осознал, что требуются более высокоуровневые функции, которые обеспечат обнаружение устойчивых конструкций, вроде тегов или атрибутов. Это необходимо, чтобы облегчить написание кода и сделать его более читаемым. Например, важно искать конструкции вида: `<tag-name ...>`.

При этом, я по-прежнему не хочу использовать построение DOM-дерева, а также регулярные выражения.

DOM-дерево достаточно большая конструкция и следовательно тяжёлая в построении.

Регулярные выражения также тяжёлая конструкция. В данной задаче нужны лишь очень ограниченные её возможности. Кроме того, оказывается, что читать их невозможно.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106365/discussion-on-question-by-hedgehogues--dom-).

Answer (score 5):

Вы рассматриваете слишком простые случаи, типа найти `<z>` и отрезать до `</z>`.

Чуть более сложный пример: `<tag param1="123" param2='345' param3="678">`, просто начните переставлять местами  порядок трёх вариантов параметров (факториал трёх), вы получите взрывной рост сложности регулярок.

Пример с недавнего сайта:

```
<div class="can-control-extended has-quote-images-settings-container user-answer  lesson-related-data type-mission_answer  status-accepted answer-with-controls"
     data-id="43814576"
     data-object-type-id="8"
     data-user-id="70420225"
     data-lesson-id="114595360"
     data-lesson-name="Обсуждение занятия 2"
     data-lesson-ugc-default-tags="">
```

И когда мне нужно написать сложное условие, а не просто status-accepted — намного проще один раз распарсить, сложить в класс, а далее использовать linq.

В программировании же удобно применять единообразный подход, унифицированные инструменты. Построенное DOM-дерево выигрывает на сложных случаях, делается без шпаргалки по памяти и на средних и тем более лёгких, но главное -- вы помните один, унифицированный подход, а не тут поиск и замена подстрок, тут регулярка, тут хитрая регулярка, тут сломай себе мозг регулярка.

Comment: я не понял пример :)

Comment: Не получу. Я всегда могу зацепиться за `param1` (=. И всё в шоколаде. В чём проблема?

Comment: Не надо регулярок

Comment: У вас есть функция `Extract()`. Вы в неё передаёте ту подстроку, которая идёт до данных и ту подстроку, которая идёт после данных. Для извлечения `param1` достаточно: `Extract('param1="', '" ')`. Нет здесь взрывного роста

Comment: Если у Вас сложный пример, Вы всегда можете найти подстроку, с которой начинается не сложный пример: `Ctx('<tag', Extract('param1="', '" '))`

Comment: Да, я не смогу обрабатывать все возможные случаи. Но это и не нужно. Зачем? В реальности бывает очень ограниченные варианты вёрстки. Не бывает полного хаоса. И в этом плюс.

Comment: @hedgehogues, здесь скорее проблема если надо выбрать `tag` с несколькими `param` или лучше `class`. А если добавится вложенность селекторов все становится еще сложнее

Answer (score 1):

Минус можно поставить за плохое оформление темы: в заголовке и метках не указан html. Я, увидев заголовок и первое предложение, решил, что речь об xml. Сразу же я подумал о трёх основных классах .NET (я пишу в основном на C#, поэтому буду опираться на свой опыт): XmlDocument, XPathDocument, XDocument для работы с xml - только первый из них строит DOM, два других - нет.

Ладно, речь о html. Однако, xhtml является well-formed xml, поэтому его можно парсить инструментами для работы с xml. Отсюда имеем множество библиотек без построения DOM.

---

А почемы вы не пишете на ассемблере? Ведь это несложно: записываем число в регистр, заносим код команды в другой регистр, выполняем... Однако, на языке высокого уровня производительность программиста во много раз выше. Согласен ли ваш работодатель оплачивать то время, пока вы будете возиться с асмом или ручным парсингом? Не быстрее ли и дешевле заюзать парсер?

---

Опять же, в дотнете есть потоковые html-reader'ы. Они не строят объектную модель в памяти, а парсят документ налету, не сохраняя уже просмотренные узлы. Поэтому памяти тратится минимум. Я не работал именно с ними, но много использовал потоковый XmlReader - его скорость такова, что почти равна скорости чтения с hdd.

---

Да, я знаю, что есть *очень* медленные библиотеки парсинга. Разница в скорости работы может быть в *десятки* раз.

Возможно, в используемых вами языках программирования / платформах / технологиях нет удовлетворяющего по скорости парсера. Тогда стоит поискать их в других языках и, если это возможно, использовать тем или иным способом.

Раз уж вы озаботились этой темой, значит это для вас критично. Следовательно, нужно было начинать именно с этого: выбрать самую критичную часть вашего приложения (парсинг html), поискать самый подходящий способ (язык, платформу) для этой цели (возможно, это окажется C#, или Java, или Си, или ассемблер) и уже на нём реализовывать ядро. А не наоборот: сперва взять язык, который в дальнейшем окажется не подходящим по скорости выполнения, по скорости разработки, по стоимости поддержки, по потребляемой памяти и пр., и героически вручную писать тонны кода.